# Looping Range of Numbers & Appending to df.col using pandas or itertools

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply

I would like to iterate a range of numbers through a dataframe column.

```
data = {'NAME': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy','Tina3', 'Jake2', 'Amy1','Jake3', 'Amy2' ], 
        'REPORTS': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 12, 13, 63, 22, 64]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['col'] = 0
range = [1,2,3]
```

I am would like the output to look like the below:

```
Jason  4    1
Molly  24   2
Tina   31   3
Jake   2    1
Amy    3    2
```

I've tried:

```
for row in df['col']:
    d['col'].append(range)

df['col'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['col']+range)
```

Comment: I think the counts should be  [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]. Can you check again please?

Comment: it is unclear why people are getting 1,2,3 could you clarify what designates someone getting a certain number?

Comment: We just want to iterate through each row and apply the range of number in order repetitively until the end of the dataframe.

Comment: so you just wanted to repetitively assign the numbers 1-3? if so I will remove my answer as the other 2 answers satisfy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `itertools.cycle` to cycle through your range for the length of the dataframe:

```
from itertools import cycle

c = cycle(range(1,4))

df['new_column'] = [next(c) for _ in range(len(df))]

>>> df
    NAME  REPORTS  new_column
0  Jason        4           1
1  Molly       24           2
2   Tina       31           3
3   Jake        2           1
4    Amy        3           2
5  Tina3       12           3
6  Jake2       13           1
7   Amy1       63           2
8  Jake3       22           3
9   Amy2       64           1
```

An alternative would be to use `np.tile` to repeat your range, but this seems less readable to me:

```
df['new_column'] = pd.np.tile(range(1,4), (len(df)//3)+1)[:len(df)]
```

Comment: This way works for me. Thank you. Is there a way to do this in pandas and not import itertools?  We are limited on the packages we can have installed and pandas is already installed on the machines.

Comment: `itertools` should be bundled into most python installations (it's in the python standard library). Alternatively, see my second answer with `pd.np.tile`.

Comment: The second way worked as well - I guess I overlooked it.  Thank you for the help and quick response.

Answer (score 0):

use `lambda` along `axis=1`
example code is

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'NAME': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy','Tina3', 'Jake2', 'Amy1','Jake3', 'Amy2' ], 
        'REPORTS': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 12, 13, 63, 22, 64]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['col'] = 0
range = [1,2,3]
df['col'] = df.apply(lambda x: range[x.name % len(range)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

output is

```
NAME  REPORTS  col
0  Jason        4    1
1  Molly       24    2
2   Tina       31    3
3   Jake        2    1
4    Amy        3    2
5  Tina3       12    3
6  Jake2       13    1
7   Amy1       63    2
8  Jake3       22    3
9   Amy2       64    1
[Finished in 1.1s]
```

Comment: This worked also - thank you for the recommendation.